# JavaFX Как узнать координаты курсора, который находится в TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, jtextfield

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нашел только getCaretPosition(), но это немного не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на класс `TextFieldSkin` он наследует от `TextInputControlSkin`. В нем содержится экземпляр класса `Path`, который показывает курсор, `caretPath`. Но он объявлен с модификатором `protected`.

```
protected final Path caretPath = new Path();
```

Чтобы получить к нему доступ, надо создать наследника. В нем мы и получим доступ к нашему курсору. И при каждом изменении курсора мы будет отлавливать его и обрабатывать.

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldCaretControlSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
    public TextFieldCaretControlSkin(TextField textField, Stage stage) {
        super(textField);
        // следим за изменениями layoutBoundProperty нашего экземпляра Path
        caretPath.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable,
                            Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
                // координаты курсора относительно TextField-а
                double x = newValue.getMaxX();
                double y = newValue.getMaxY();

                // искомая координата
                Point2D p = caretPath.localToScene(x, y);

                System.out.println(p.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Этим же способом можно получить координаты курсора от всех наследователей `TextInputControlSkin`.

Comment: Узнав расположение курсора можно добавлять различные `Popup`-ы, добавлять анимации и т.д. рядом с курсором.